# Redirection in Class Based Views Doesn't Completly Work

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-url-reverse

**views.py:**

```
class LoveLetterCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = LoveLetter
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login') # NOT WORKING

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login') # WORKING
    template_name = 'love_letters/signup.html'
```

Why it would work in one CreateView but not in the other?

I tried:
`def get_success_url(self):` - NOT WORKING.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Your LoveLetterCreateView must be throwing error, or form is invalid.